# Search through array from XML in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, xml, datepicker

I am trying to use PHP to parse through an XML list and filter and paginate the results to match the selected date of a hidden input using datepicker. However, when trying to use PHP to search through my array (after converting to json and back to a php array), I am getting no output. Any help on this would be awesome!

**My code:**

```
function LoadXML()
{
    $xmlURL = 'http://rhpl.evanced.info/signup/eventsxml.asp?dm=xml&lib=all&alltime=1&ds=&ds=6/15/2016&de=6/15/2018';
    $xmlFile = simplexml_load_file($xmlURL);
    $json = json_encode($xmlFile);
    $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
    $selectedDate = $_POST['selectedDate'];

    echo "<pre>";

    $search = array_search($selectedDate, $array);
    echo $search;

    foreach ($array['item'] as $item) {
        $title = $item['title'];
        $date = $item['date'];

        //echo "<div id='event-item'>";
        //echo "<span id='title'>" . $title . "</span>" . "<br />";
        //echo "<span id='date'>" . $date . "</span><br/>";
        //echo "</div>";
    }

    //print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

**My Array Output:**

```
Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => English Matters Book Group for English Language Learners
                    [date] => Wednesday, June 15, 2016
                    [time] => 10:00 AM
                    [enddate] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [description] => 
Wednesday Mornings, 10 -11:30, Second Floor Conference room
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
 $search = array_search($selectedDate, array_column($array, 'date'));
```

> You need to determine which column the search will be made. Using array_column() you select the desired column of the array, 'date'.

See more on [xfoxawy php.net contribution on array_column() function](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php#116635)

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @bub Thanks for the tip. I have just completed my answer.